# Trying to center a progress bar on an image

Tags: android, xml

I have an layout which is implemented and looks nice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/splash_layout">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

but i needed to add a progress bar on the center of the image, so i have this starting code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when i try to combine the two, it pushes the image off the screen.   I cant use the graphical layout to get a render of it for some reason, and was trying to see if i could get this working.

My combined idea was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/splash_layout">
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

it just seems to push the image off the screen or something and i cant quite figure out whats going on.

if there a way to take the relative layout out of the dom by having it become relative or absolute?  then the image would slide up but the relative layout will still be at 0,0 with height and width == parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/splash_layout" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The documentation on layouts is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), "fill_parent" is deprecated since the 8-th version of SDK. Use "match_parent" instead.

Comment: can i apply padding the progress bar to push it up some?  For example, my image has some text underneath the progress bar and it looks kinda sloppy.  I wasnt sure if i could utilize layout_padding and centerInParent

Comment: There is no property called 'layout_padding' in View class. There are 'layout_margin*' params, 'paddingLeft/paddingTop/etc' and 'padding'. As for using them in the RelativeLayout - try and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgCapaLivroCadastro"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/myPicture" />

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/pbImgLivroCadEdit"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you apply padding to it as well, so that way it is not centered in parent (the progress bar) by giving it some padding?